# Reference error function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // convert bytes into friendly format
        function bytesToSize(bytes) {
            var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
            if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        };

        // check for selected crop region
        function checkForm() {
            if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
            $('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press Upload').show();
            return false;
        };

        // update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
        function updateInfo(e) {
            $('#x1').val(e.x);
            $('#y1').val(e.y);
            $('#x2').val(e.x2);
            $('#y2').val(e.y2);
            $('#w').val(e.w);
            $('#h').val(e.h);
        };

        // clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
        function clearInfo() {
            $('.info #w').val('');
            $('.info #h').val('');
        };

        // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
        var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

        function fileSelectHandler() {

            // get selected file
            var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

            // hide all errors
            $('.error').hide();

            // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
            var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
            if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
                $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
                return;
            }

            // check for file size
            if (oFile.size > 250 * 1024) {
                $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file').show();
                return;
            }

            // preview element
            var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

            // prepare HTML5 FileReader
            var oReader = new FileReader();
            oReader.onload = function (e) {

                // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
                oImage.src = e.target.result;
                oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler

                    // display step 2
                    $('.step2').fadeIn(500);

                    // display some basic image info
                    var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
                    $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
                    $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
                    $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);

                    // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
                    if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {
                        jcrop_api.destroy();
                        jcrop_api = null;
                        $('#preview').width(oImage.naturalWidth);
                        $('#preview').height(oImage.naturalHeight);
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // initialize Jcrop
                        $('#preview').Jcrop({
                            minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                            aspectRatio: 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                            bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                            bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                            onChange: updateInfo,
                            onSelect: updateInfo,
                            onRelease: clearInfo
                        }, function () {

                            // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                            var bounds = this.getBounds();
                            boundx = bounds[0];
                            boundy = bounds[1];

                            // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                            jcrop_api = this;
                        });
                    }, 3000);

                };
            };

            // read selected file as DataURL
            oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
        }
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="profileUploadModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload profilepicture</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="bbody">

                                        <!-- upload form -->
                                        <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
                                            <!-- hidden crop params -->
                                            <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />

                                            <h2>Step1: Please select image file</h2>
                                            <div><input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" /></div>

                                            <div class="error"></div>

                                            <div class="step2">
                                                <h2>Step2: Please select a crop region</h2>
                                                <img id="preview" />

                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <label>File size</label> <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
                                                    <label>Type</label> <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
                                                    <label>Image dimension</label> <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                                                    <label>W</label> <input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                                                    <label>H</label> <input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fileSelectHandler is not defined

I do not understand why. As I can see, the function Is already implemented? So Why do I get this reference error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of those functions to be in document.onReady.

Any function declared in the document.ready scope must also be called from within it. If not, they lose that scope when the ready() method exits. So it does not exist in the scope you are trying to call it from, hence your error.

Define as follows:

```js
    function bytesToSize(bytes) {
      var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
      if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
      var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
      return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
    };

     // check for selected crop region
    function checkForm() {
      if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
      $('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press Upload').show();
      return false;
    };

     // update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
    function updateInfo(e) {
      $('#x1').val(e.x);
      $('#y1').val(e.y);
      $('#x2').val(e.x2);
      $('#y2').val(e.y2);
      $('#w').val(e.w);
      $('#h').val(e.h);
    };

     // clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
    function clearInfo() {
      $('.info #w').val('');
      $('.info #h').val('');
    };

     // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
    var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

    function fileSelectHandler(e) {

      alert("I'm here!");

      // get selected file
      var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

      // hide all errors
      $('.error').hide();

      // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
      var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
      if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
        return;
      }

      // check for file size
      if (oFile.size > 250 * 1024) {
        $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file').show();
        return;
      }

      // preview element
      var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

      // prepare HTML5 FileReader
      var oReader = new FileReader();
      oReader.onload = function(e) {

        // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
        oImage.src = e.target.result;
        oImage.onload = function() { // onload event handler

          // display step 2
          $('.step2').fadeIn(500);

          // display some basic image info
          var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
          $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
          $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
          $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);

          // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
          if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {
            jcrop_api.destroy();
            jcrop_api = null;
            $('#preview').width(oImage.naturalWidth);
            $('#preview').height(oImage.naturalHeight);
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            // initialize Jcrop
            $('#preview').Jcrop({
              minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
              aspectRatio: 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
              bgFade: true, // use fade effect
              bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
              onChange: updateInfo,
              onSelect: updateInfo,
              onRelease: clearInfo
            }, function() {

              // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
              var bounds = this.getBounds();
              boundx = bounds[0];
              boundy = bounds[1];

              // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
              jcrop_api = this;
            });
          }, 3000);

        };
      };

      // read selected file as DataURL
      oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // convert bytes into friendly format



    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profileUploadModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload profilepicture</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="bbody">

          <!-- upload form -->
          <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
            <!-- hidden crop params -->
            <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />

            <h2>Step1: Please select image file</h2>
            <div>
              <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" />
            </div>

            <div class="error"></div>

            <div class="step2">
              <h2>Step2: Please select a crop region</h2>
              <img id="preview" />

              <div class="info">
                <label>File size</label>
                <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
                <label>Type</label>
                <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
                <label>Image dimension</label>
                <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                <label>W</label>
                <input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                <label>H</label>
                <input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want a bunch of global functions, define the `onchange` handler inside the document ready handler instead of using the inline `onchange` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your function fileSelectHandler() is defined inside of another function. Try to move it out of "$(document).ready(function () {..." block